# How was this repeating and blurring created?

Tags: lighting, color-filters

How do I achieve the effect below where the repeating subject getting blurry each time it repeats with every reflection, and the subject repeating at a slant in the picture?

[image: multiple reflections on wall live]

Answer (score 2):

Recursively including an image within itself is known as [mise en abyme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mise_en_abyme) or the [Droste effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Droste_effect).

- Mise en abyme refers to coat of arms within a coat of arms.  It was later applied to recursive art.

  [image: coat of arms]
- Droste effect is named for a Dutch brand of cocao in which a woman is holding a tin of cocao containing an image of herself holding a tin of cocao containing an image ...

  [image: Droste Effect]

The image in question was created using a [video feedback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_feedback) loop.  A video camera was pointed at a projection of its own output.  The blurry, fading appearance is produced by defocusing the lens and extraneous light.

- YouTube: [Video Feedback Loop using a camera and a projector](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nb1OMNlPdBc)

[image: video feedback]

Another way to create the effect is with mirrors facing each other.  Frosting one mirror would create the blurred fade, but that is not how this particular image was created because the object on the right is not reflected in the wall.

Yet another way to create this effect is using a photo editor to repeatedly paste a resized copy into the image.  Use standard editing tools to blur and fade each copy after pasting.  A similar method can be used to create a variation in which a photo spirals into itself.

- Discover Digital Photography: [How to create a Droste Effect recursive photo](https://www.discoverdigitalphotography.com/2014/how-to-create-a-droste-effect-recursive-photo/)
- Flickr: [New Droste Effect Tutorial](https://www.flickr.com/photos/joshsommers/2751591134/in/set-72157594515046947)

[image: Spiral Droste Effect]

Comment: Thank you so much!